# Data not getting saved in Firebase database from android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the new Firebase console. I am trying to save an object to the database but its not getting saved. Following is the code.

```
DatabaseReference mFirebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mFirebaseRef.push().setValue(object, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference reference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to write message", databaseError.toException());
                }
            }
        });
```

the 'object' is created properly. There is no error I am getting and I have checked in debugging that the onComplete method is not getting triggered. 
Security Rule is also true for write.

Comment: Can you show how you create `object`? Or at least the minimal `object` with which you can reproduce the problem?

Comment: object is a java class reference. Object object = new Object(params). The code is not working with Hash Map also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that [DatabaseReference.CompletionListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener) fires "when an operation has been acknowledged by the Database servers".  Is it possible you did not have a network connection at the time you ran your test?  I copied your code and ran it successfully on a phone with `object` defined like this:

```
Object object = new String("Test");
```

I then enabled airplane mode, re-ran the code and observed the behavior you describe.  The completion listener did not fire until I disabled airplane mode and a network connection was established.

Example code for checking the status of your network connection is provided in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

Comment: I did not have the Internet permission in manifest. Thanks, It was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
mFirebaseRef.push().setValue(object).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() 
{
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                           if(task.isSuccessful()){
                               // write code for successfull operation
                           }
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

.push will generate a random key on which your data will stored if you do not use .push it will overwrite on previous stored data.